# Pre-trained models for semantic segmentation of satellite images

Tags: semantic-segmentation

I'd like to use semantic segmentation of satellite images but I don't have the processing power to train existing models or producing one my own.

Ideally, I'm looking for a U-Net CNN model that can be used together with [Smoothly-Blend-Image-Patches](https://github.com/Vooban/Smoothly-Blend-Image-Patches)

Is anyone aware of any pre-trained model of this kind?